# Javascript error parsing http response

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http

I am trying to parse the response from the www.skiddle.com API in Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.skiddle.com/api/v1/events/search/?api_key=myapikey' + '&latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + long + '&radius=800&eventcode=LIVE&order=distance&description=1',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
        var list = [];
        $(response).find("results").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var obj = {
                   "eventname": el.find("eventname").text(),
                   "imageurl" : el.find("imageurl").text(),
                  };
        list.push(obj);
        });
```

The response actually has a `results` property with one element in the array:

```
{error: 0, totalcount: "1", pagecount: 1, results: Array(1)}
```

but I can't seem to parse it correctly, `$(response).find("results")` returns nothing.

Comment: Please share the value of response: `console.log( response )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that there will be a `result` array property in your response, you may simply use  `response.results` which gives you the array.

```
success: function(response) {

  $.each(response.results,function(indx,item){
       console.log(item);
       var obj = {  
                    eventname: item.eventname,
                    imageurl : item.imageurl
                 };
      list.push(obj);
  });

}
```

Assuming `list` is an array defined earlier.

Also if you are sure there will be only one item in the array, you do not need a loop, you can access it via `response.results[0]`

```
success: function(response) {
  if (response.results.length>0) {
     var obj = { eventName: response.results[0].eventname,
                 imageurl : response.results[0].imageurl };
     list.push(obj);
  }
}
```

I also noticed that the your new object has the same property names as the object you are iterating. In that case, you can simply add the same object

```
 list.push(response.results[0]);
```

Of course this will add the first item as it is , which means if that has additional properties (other than eventname and imageurl) those will be present in the item you are adding to list now..

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is a `JSON`, you are trying to parse it as `XML`.

The `list` you are trying to get can be obtained by simply using

```
success: function(response) {
    var list = (response.results || []).map(function(result) {
        return {  
            eventname: result.eventname,
            imageurl : result.imageurl
        };
    });
}
```